# my query is incorrect. convert_tz is causing incorrect values

Tags: mysql, sql, convert-tz

I use convert_tz for many queries that I use daily. Yesterday, it began yielding incorrect values.

I seperated these lines from my query, and ran them separately.

```
SELECT 
CURDATE() - interval 1 day as yesterday,
CURDATE() as today, 
CONVERT_TZ(CURDATE(), @@session.time_zone, 'America/New_York') as Today_CTZ;
```

This will return 3 columns, and it should show yestderday's date, todays date, and todays date.
This is what is returned instead.

| yesterday | today | Today_CTZ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-11 | 2023-01-12 | 2023-01-11 19:00:00 |

It has returned yesterdays date, todays date, and yesterdays date.

This query was run on 1/12/23 at 9:20 AM

This is what it **should** produce

| yesterday | today | Today_CTZ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-11 | 2023-01-12 | 2023-01-12 19:00:00 |

Why is it doing this?

Comment: What is your session timezone?

Comment: @Barmar central time, though the issue is the same using @@global.time_zone

Comment: central time is only 1 hour different from eastern time, why do you expect the time to be 19:00:00?

Comment: @barmar, that's a valid point but not the issue. the issue, is that convert_tz is pulling 24 hours behind the date it should

Comment: If the session time zone is 5 hours ahead of New York, converting the time zone subtracts 5 hours, which goes to 19:00 of the previous day.

Comment: You'd get this result if the session time zone is GMT, for instance.